# mapping tree graph so edges point to next-oldest sibling?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, graph-isomorphism

Is there a name for or relevant work on graphs constructed by taking a tree graph as input and changing the edge targets from the parent to the next-oldest sibling (if it exists)? It has come up in some work I'm doing and I'm not even sure what to search for in a literature search.